# where to place customer jar in maven project structure

Tags: maven

I have a dependency application jar from other maven applications,and currently added it to my application path,

I want to know how this application related jar can be automatically moved my local repository folders.

I think it should be placed in somewhere in maven project folder structure so that when maven build the module it automatically moves to the repository.

Comment: Best is to install a repository manager and install that artifact into the repository manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependent project:

If built with maven, you would issue a mvn install, when building it.

If not built with maven, install it locally using mvn install:install-file

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html

Comment: I did this way,but my collegue did it differently , just by putting somewhere in the project path,it actually created in maven repository automatically. I am sure he did not do install:install-file

Comment: :) he is not in this country!